# How to test whether the value of a Java field gotten by reflection is null?

Tags: java, reflection, null, field

I have

```
Field f = this.getClass().getFields()[0];
```

I need to know if `f`'s value in `this` is `null` or not. There are many methods like `getInt()` and `getDouble()`, but I have not found a method like `Object getData()` or `isNull()`.  Is there such a method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`field.get(target)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) returns `Object`. So you can check`if (field.get(this) == null) {..}`

If the field is primitive, it will get wrapped. `int` -> `Integer`, `char` -> `Character`, etc.

Comment: @stevemoretz No need to swear. `target` is the object the field belongs to. For example: `SomeClass object = new SomeClass(); Field field = object.getDelcaredField("fieldName"); field.get(object)`; So in this case `object` is the target `Bozho` meant above.

Comment: @Nom1fan That actually was a long time ago.I figured it out myself but anyway thanks.And that really wasn't a swear.sorry anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the field from the object then check if it is null

```
Field f = this.getClass().getFields()[0];
if (f.get(this) == null)
  ...
```

Comment: and what if it has a primitive type?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't search well enough: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29

Call this method, and check if the returned object is null.

Answer (score 0):

use `Object obj=f.get(this)` and check whether the returned object(in this case obj) is null or not